# WPF-based graph visualization

Tags: wpf, 3d, graph

Does anybody know any sample of graph(vertices connected with edges) 3D visualization written on WPF or Silverlight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only graph viewer for Silverlight I've seen is part of the [Silverlight Bag-O-Tricks](http://www.codeplex.com/BagOTricks). I believe this is a port of a WPF project.

I'm not sure if this will meet your 3D requirements. The two 3D graph viewers i've seen are WilmaScope which can find it on sourceforge, and [UBIGraph](http://ubietylab.net/ubigraph/) which has a free basic version.

Also, if your interested there's a good package for flash called Prefuse (prefuse.org) which provides graph layouts and much more.